# Determine time given algorithmic complexity as input grows?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Consider the time required to solve a problem, represented by `f(n)`, and for sufficiently large inputs of size `k`, the time required to solve a problem is `t`. What is the typical method of determining how long, in terms of `t`, is necessary to solve a problem, for different kinds of `f(n)` and `k`?

For example, when `f(n)` is `Θ(n)`, and the input is `2k`, we know that the time is approximately `2t`. But what is the standard method of determining the time, in terms of `t`, for problems like this? For example:

1. When f(n) is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>) and the input is k<sup>2</sup> ?
2. f(n) is Θ(2n) and the input size is k+3 ?
3. f(n) is Θ(lg n) and the input size is 4k ?
4. f(n) is Θ(n!) and the input size is k+2 ?

This question is not asking for answers to those scenarios per se, rather, how to go about expressing the time, in terms of `t`, given the parameters above.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You seem to be asking, "If $f$ is some function and $n$ is some function of $k$, what is $f(n)$ in terms of $k$?" If that's what you _are_ asking, I don't understand why you don't just substitute the function of $k$ for $n$ to get your answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with algorithm analysis, and everything with understanding the definitions of Landau notation. (Landau terms tell you very little about actual running times.)

Answer (score 3):

The standard method is to heuristically assume that a bound of the form $\Theta(g(n))$ can be approximated by $Cg(n)$ for some constant $C$, though in some cases this approximation is not justified, and the "constant" $C$ fluctuates (but is bounded on both sides).

Considering your first example, if $f(n) \approx Cn^3$ then $f(k^2) \approx Ck^6 = (Ck^3)^2/C \approx f(k)^2/C$. Unfortunately, the dependence on $C$ cannot be eliminated, but $C$ can be approximated empirically, though you should take such results with a grain of salt.